# Main Site With 000WebHost

Tags: xhtml, web, program-entry-point

I am trying to create a site with xhtml I have it done I just need to figure out how to upload it

I am using 000webhost as my web hoster but whenever I go on my main page it says

index of/

then it says all of my sites

I want to go directly to m main site

how do I do that?

Comment: It sounds like your host is not pointing to your domain name's root, but rather `index of/` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to:

Members area,
Login,
Select in Action GoTo Cpanel and then:

You should configure your FTP servers, upload an index.html or index.php file and put your main information there.

EDIT:
You should upload everything to your public_html folder always, you should see a file that should say do_not_upload_here before that folder. 
Public html is what what it sounds like. The html container folder that contains what will be visible*. (*VERY rough explanation)

You can use their file manager or an FTP client for this pourpose.

BTW beware of the affiliate programe fo 000webhost, check it out, total hoax (the web hosting is very good for being free).

I´ll gladly expand if you have any doubts.

Here is a good FTP basic tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I85sldEvLuY&feature=related

Comment: I got filezilla their FTP client but I don't know were to put my index.html... do I put it in the root directory or do I put it in the public_html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `index.html` file in your root directory with your host? Without one of those (or another similar index file), you will just see a directory listing of your site.